# Как сделать защита api по определенному token?

Tags: yii

Мне нужно и другого сайта, чтобы брал данные польователя по api и все, не создание записи, не редактирование и прочее. То есть мне нужен статичный токен создать и все для данного сайта, чтобы левые запросы не могли брать данные с этого сайта.
Но выходит что я в браузере или postman делаю запрос хоть secret_token или другой, то у меня выходит всегда ошибка

```
{"name":"Forbidden","message":"Доступ запрещен","code":0,"status":403,"type":"yii\\web\\ForbiddenHttpException"}
```

Моя реализация

```
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    const TOKEN = 'secret';

    public $modelClass = 'backend\models\User';
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator']['class'] = QueryParamAuth::className();
        $behaviors['authenticator']['tokenParam'] = 'token';
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'user' => false,
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'allow' => true,
                            'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                                $data = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams();

                                return isset($data['token']) && $data['token'] === 'secret';
                            },
                        ],
                    ],
                    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('Доступ запрещен');
                    }
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам надо убрать поведение `$behaviors['authenticator']`

Comment: @OlyLad А зачем убрать?

Comment: Можете открыть код этого класса и посмотреть, что там происходит. Там авторизация пользователя по access-token, т.е. метод `$user->loginByAccessToken()`. Судя по вопросу это не то что вам надо.

Comment: @OlyLad Понял вас